# Conditional validation ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

In my model I have properties

```
    [Required]
    public decimal Prefix { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{9}$", ErrorMessage = "Message")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
```

How can I change conditional for regular expression when it depends of Prefix value, e.g when Prefix is 49 Phone should has 9 numbers but in other way it should contain only number without checking length

Comment: You need to write you own conditional validation attribute - [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for:)